# I try to running ionic app on my android device and there are errors

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework

The errors i get:

```
20:29   Gradle sync failed: Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.60-eap-25.
            Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.60-eap-25/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.60-eap-25.pom
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.60-eap-25/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.60-eap-25.jar
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.60-eap-25/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.60-eap-25.pom
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.60-eap-25/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.60-eap-25.jar
            https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.60-eap-25/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.60-eap-25.pom
            https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.60-eap-25/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.60-eap-25.jar
            Required by:
            unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradl... (show balloon)

20:29   NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=4.6, NDK version is UNKNOWN
```

I install NDK

**local.properties file:**

sdk.dir=C:\Users\Chen Fridman\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

ndk.dir=C:\Users\Chen Fridman\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\20.1.5948944

**build.gradle (project:android) file:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

........................................

**build.gradle (app) file:**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
  compileSdkVersion 29
  buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "io.ionic.simhatzkenti"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  })
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+'
  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


#Tue Jan 30 13:14:22 CST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

i really nedd help , i am stuck!
thank you very much!

Comment: Could you please full both `build.gradle` app and `build.gradle` project files?

Comment: Hi, i update my question
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the instructions for android installation of ionic apps?  Generally you should not need an NDK.

https://ionicframework.com/docs

https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/android

Answer (score 0):

Here is your fixed files.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'

    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
  compileSdkVersion 29
  buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "io.ionic.simhatzkenti"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


#Tue Jan 30 13:14:22 CST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Comment: Where is the fix in all of this?